# Issue with receiving Apple ID account change notification emails

Tags: email, security, apple-id

I was changing the password and recovery key to my Apple ID tonight. Every other time I've done this, I receive a notification email for both password and recovery key changes and then another notification email is sent to my secondary email about the recovery key.

However, after I did this and logged back into both email accounts (I had changed passwords for these email accounts about five minutes earlier before making the Apple ID changes), there was only one email notifying me about the password change in my primary email's inbox, and no email about the recovery key change in my secondary email's inbox.

Is there a chance that somehow, in this one case, Apple did not send me an email regarding the recovery key change? I've tested this issue out after and I've received all email notifications I expect to receive when I change my Apple ID password and recovery key with no issue. Or is someone most likely trying to mess with me?

I did this all on a Macbook with a recently erased drive and a reinstalled OS via Internet Recovery. I am (overly?) paranoid about the security of my machine ever since a couple of months ago, someone phished a password of mine on an old Macbook.

Both emails come from `appleid@id.apple.com`, but the reply-to email addresses are different (`appleid_gben@email.apple.com` for the password email, `appleid_usen@email.apple.com` for the recovery key email).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think anyone is messing with you. 
- Have you checked spam folders? 
- Check your email's trash can.

There is always the chance that the email failed to send from apple's side or failed to reach you in transit. But if you tried again and everything is working fine like before, then I don't think someone is messing with you.

Comment: I didn't think to check spam/trash as it wouldn't have been marked as spam and I definitely didn't delete it as I was under the impression that I didn't receive it. Just checked both, nothing there.

But I'm thinking if they're sent from the same email address, it definitely wouldn't be a fault from Apple's side, given that I got the email about the password change. I'm seriously perplexed.